# How to use one project as a local dependency in another project React js

Tags: reactjs

Hi i have created two projects the first . Project A is the main project and i have created one more project , project B.Now i want to use project B as a local dependency in my project A.
As I tried this way in my package.json file of the project A.but I am not sure how to do it in a right way.

```
preinstall:"cd ./projectB && npm i &&npm run build&& npm run copy"
```

Comment: Use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link) or [`yarn link`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link). This is assuming that project B is in a publishable state, i.e. has a `package.json` file that tells npm/yarn to locate the main file.

Answer (score 0):

in package.json you can add the dependency :

"newlocaldependency" : "../project1"